# Unwanted Carthesian Product

Tags: sql, join, multiple-tables

I'm supposed to write a SQL query for our Visitor Management System.

To be precise I had one, but thanks to an Database Construction error or Something from a Third Party. There were Entries missing because of missing Values in a Table. The management database assigns a numeric Visitor ID. This Id is the only Key implemented.

To get the missing persons I need to write a query over three tables which are joined on the same identifier, the `Visitior ID`.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VisitorBooking.Arrival ASC) AS Nr,
    Personalstamm.idPersonalstamm,
    CASE VisitRating.rating 
       WHEN 3 THEN 'Sehr Gut' 
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Gut' 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Nicht so Gut' 
       ELSE 'Sonstiges' 
    END AS Bewertung, 
    VisitRating.Comment,
    VisitorBooking.Arrival,
    Personalstamm.Name,
    Personalstamm.FirstName,
    Personalstamm.Company,
    Personalstamm.Stadt
FROM
    Personalstamm 
INNER JOIN
    VisitRating ON Personalstamm.idPersonalstamm =  VisitRating.idPersonalstamm 
INNER JOIN
    VisitorBooking ON Personalstamm.idPersonalstamm =  VisitorBooking.idVisitor
WHERE
    Personalstamm.idPersonalstamm IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    VisitorBooking.Arrival
```

In `Personalstamm` are the personal dates like name and so on.

In `VisitRating` is a rating of the stay and a comment.

And I need `Visitorbooking` to catch the people who are not in visiting for unknown reasons.

My problem is, it does what it should do but builds the unwanted carthesian product out of `Visitorbooking` and `Visitor Rating`. What can I do to not get this?

Distinct didn't work, Group By also didn't work.

Sample data:

**Personalstamm**:

```
Name: x
Firstname: MR.
Primary Key ID: 1
Company: X-Files
Town: Gravity Falls
```

**VisitorBooking**:

```
Arrival: 06.13.2018 00:00:00
Departure: 01:30:57
ID Visitor: 1
```

**VisitRating**:

```
Rating: 3
Comment: I'm anonymous
Date: 06.13.2018
Foreign Key ID: 1
```

It should like

```
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 06.13.2018 Sehr Gut I'm anonymous.
```

But there were several cases where everything from `Visitrating` was empty why I had to rewrite to get:

```
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 06.13.2018 00:00:00 NULL NULL.
```

I replaced date with arrival.

But what I get when he visits more than once is:

```
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 06.13.2018 00:00:00 Sehr Gut NULL.
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 06.13.2018 00:00:00 GUT NULL.
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 06.13.2018 00:00:00 Nicht so GUT NULL.

1 MR. X Gravity Falls 07.13.2018 00:00:00 Sehr Gut NULL.
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 07.13.2018 00:00:00 GUT NULL.
1 MR. X Gravity Falls 07.13.2018 00:00:00 Nicht so GUT NULL.
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Two choices, use EXISTS if you want to check if a personalstamm exists on the other 2 tables, or join against 1 row per each personalstamm (using cross apply with top 1, or a subquery with a rownumber). Tagging which DBMS you are using will help people find a solution for you.

Comment: I have to use a Third Party Managment System provided by the Visitormangment System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want something like this:

```
select . . . 
From Personalstamm p left join
     (select vr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by idPersonalstamm order by idPersonalstamm) as seqnum VisitRating vr
     ) vr
     on p.idPersonalstamm =  vr.idPersonalstamm left join
     (select vb.*,
             row_number() over (partition by idPersonalstamm order by idPersonalstamm) as seqnum       from VisitorBooking vb
     ) vb
     on p.idPersonalstamm = vb.idVisitor and
        vp.seqnum = vr.seqnum
where ps.idPersonalstamm is not null 
order by vb.Arrival;
```

Two important notes:

- This assumes that the number of visits is at least as big as the number of bookings.
- I introduced table aliases, so you should fix the `SELECT` clause to use them instead of the full table name.

Comment: Thanks it really worked. I've never heard about the partitions before.